# Encoding error using pyserial

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, pyserial

I use a serial connection to send SMS through 3G usb stick. It works fine but when i try to send 
messages that contains characters from the french language like 'é', 'ç' and 'à' i get error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import serial

connection = '/dev/ttyUSB6'                    # port

def sendSMS(message, telephoneNumber):
    """Send a SMS"""
    ser = serial.Serial(connection, 9600, timeout=5)  # open port
    ser.write('AT+CMGF=1\r')    
    ser.write('AT+CMGS="%s"\r' %telephoneNumber)
    ser.write(message) 
    ser.write(chr(26))


number = '123456789'
sendSMS("Championnat d'Espagne : l'Atletico sacré 18 ans après", number)
```

I need a solution to this problem. Thanks ;)

Comment: Which version of python are you using? You probably need to `encode` the text in something other than ascii.

Comment: @Tim Already did, doesn't solve it!

Comment: Make sure anything sent to pyserial is of type `bytes` by using the `b''` form for all commands. Then properly encode your SMS text. If passes `bytes`, pyserial will not try to encode the stream. Note that the encoded data should maybe not be encoded in utf-8 but rather in GSM encoding, depending on the modem and/or the receiving device.